# Visual Studio Xamarin Live Player iOS: Could not connect to the debugger

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I wanted to try Xamarin Forms and have downloaded [AzureStorage](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WebServices/AzureStorage/) sample.
Visual Studio Pro 2017 15.5.0 Preview 1.0, Xamarin 4.8.0.599, Xamarin iOS 11.4.0.76, Xamarin Forms 2.4.0.282

When I start the Live Player on iPhone (6s, iOS 11.0.3) , I am getting this:

```
Start (FileUploader.iOS, ____'s iPhone Player, ).
Attempting connection to debug address: 192.168._._:37847.
Connected to: 192.168._._:37847.
Deploying E:\____\iOS\FileUploader.iOS.csproj...
Got device info: ___'s iPhone Player (iOS) @ 192.168._._:37847
Synchronizing files...
Building and running...
Built with 0 messages.
Deploy to ___'s iPhone Player succeeded.
Could not connect to the debugger.
```

I cannot understand it, because the debugger is switched off and I am using the "Release" mode. Can you help me to find the problem?

P.S. If this can help, by trying to start the app with Live Player on Android, I am getting "Deploy to HUAWEI ____ Player succeeded." , but nothing is started or deployed. When I connect the Android tablet with cable, the app is deployed and started.

Comment: Will it happen when use "Start Without Debugging" instead of "Release" mode?

Comment: "Unable to deploy to ____'s iPhone Player. ..." Xamarin Live on iPhone goes green and then disappears.

Comment: I have the same issue. VS 15.5.0, iPhone 6s iOS 11.0.3.Cant run the app with the debugger. Running it without debugger works.

Comment: Can you debug app normally? Try testing blank app first with live player. You can also register in IIS test flight program, so you can download latest beta app of xamarin live player. It's far better